# Check to see if a process is running in the current user session

Tags: windows, powershell, process, windows-7-x64

I need help creating a powershell script that looks for a running process and if its not there launch it. Right now, the VB script I have looks for the process and launches, but because of Windows 7 Fast User Switching, that process can be running in any user session and it makes the script think its running in the current user session. Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to support Windows servers, where a single user may have multiple sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relatively simple code:

```
if (
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'explorer.exe'" | 
        where { 
            $_.GetOwner().User -eq $env:USERNAME 
        }
    ) { 
    "explorer is running for $env:username" 
}
```

This should ignore this process running for any other user than current. Just replace explorer.exe with actual process and change logic to match your need.

Comment: Thank you BartekB! This looks like a good start, it only works if the process is already running, it doesnt do anything if it isnt. I need it to also launch it if its not already running under the current user.

Comment: well... add else { start processname.exe } and you are good to go... :)

Comment: What if it has to work on Windows Server where one user can have multiple sessions? Is there some way to get the session the process is running in?